# AWS Cloudfront - incorrect images on different devices

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cloudfront

We are having an issue with some of the nationality flags images displayed next to each player on our site.

Some users have reported that they are seeing incorrect flags next to some players on an ipad and the correct flags on an iphone device for the same players.

Even if we cannot reproduce this issue, more users are experiencing this issue.
They even sent us print screens.

Does anybody encountered this specific problem?
Could it be some issue on the Cloudfront caching images?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced the exact same issue as you have, but I have had issues with older versions of the image being shown. I solved it by calculating a hash of the image and using a `?v=[hash]` query-string as the URL to the image. That way, whenever the image changed, so did the hash and I was guaranteed to get the new image because the URL had changed.

For example:

```
logo.png
```

would become:

```
logo.png?v=Jg8vv2tFgKtl33jCTxNVKztavLxy4ZauTYdibC9RnH
```

then when the image changed it would be

```
logo.png?v=XkV7RV8ZBkzcn5wvcXZ7HmGwkbik1GUZ5t7VLwQzyI
```

I suspect your users are seeing different images on different devices because those devices are getting the image from different CloudFront edge nodes, and those nodes have in turn cached different versions of your images.

You could also try invalidating your caches, but this only solves the problem for now, it doesn't guard against it happening again in the future.